# How to get XDebug configured in Aptana 1.5 w/ WAMP?

Tags: php, eclipse, wamp, xdebug, aptana

I've been trying to get XDebug working with Aptana Studio 1.5.  I already downloaded the XDebug .dll and edited the php .ini file.  phpinfo() is showing that xdebug is installed.  What I can't figure out is what to do from here to get it working.  Any help would be mucho appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

We (aptana) removed the debugger instructions for the moment, at least until we re-introduce the debugger support into the new PHP plugin.
I found a cached version of those instructions here: http://ascabe.bakufu.org/aptana/helpr-4.html (looks like someone copied and translated some of the doc to Japanese :) )

See the 'Creating a launch configuration' section. Sounds like this would be your next step.

Hope that helps!